# How to identify doc2vec instances seperately in gensim in python

Tags: python, gensim

I have a list of 1000 documents, where the first 500 belongs to documents in `movies` (i.e. list index from `0` to `499`) and the remaining 500 belings to documents in `tv series` (i.e. list index from `500` to `999`).

For movies the `document tag` starts with `movie_` (e.g., `movie_fast_and_furious`) and for tv series the document tag starts with `tv_series_` (e.g., `tv_series_the_office`)

I use these movies and tv series dataset to build a `doc2vec` model as follows.

```
from gensim.models import doc2vec
from collections import namedtuple

dataset = json.load(open(input_file))

docs = []
analyzedDocument = namedtuple('AnalyzedDocument', 'words tags')

for description in dataset:
    tags = [description[0]]
    words = description[1]
    docs.append(analyzedDocument(words, tags))

model = doc2vec.Doc2Vec(docs, vector_size = 100, window = 10, min_count = 1, workers = 4, epochs = 20)
```

Now for each `movie`, I want to get its nearest 5 `tv series` along with their cosine similarity.

I know, the function gensim provides `model.docvecs.most_similar`. However, the results of this include movies as well (which is not my intension). Is it possible to do this in gensim (I assume that the document vectors are creating in the order of the `documents list` that we provide).

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the `tags` are opaque identifiers to `Doc2Vec`. So, if there's internal distinctions to your data, you'll need to model and filter on that yourself.

So, my main recommendation would be to ask for a much larger `topn` than you need, then discard those results of the type you don't want, or in excess of the number you actually need.

(Note that every calculation of `most_similar()` requires a comparison against the whole known set of doc-tags, and using a smaller `topn` only saves some computation in sorting of those full results. So using a larger `topn`, even up to the full size of the known doc-tags, isn't as costly as you might fear.)

With just two categories, to get the 10 tv-shows closest to a query movie, you could make `topn` equal to the count of movies, minus 1 (the query), plus 10 – then in the absolute worst-case, where all movies are closer than than the 1st tv-show, you'd still get 10 valid tv-show results.

(The `most_similar()` function also includes a `restrict_vocab` parameter. It takes an int count, and limits results to only the 1st that-many items, in the internal storage order. So if in fact the 1st 500 documents were all tv-shows, `restrict_vocab=500` would give only results from that subset. However, I wouldn't recommend relying on this, as (a) it'd only work for one category that was front-loaded, not any others; (b) ideally for training, you *wouldn't* clump all similar documents together, but shuffle them to be interspersed with contrasting documents. Generally `Word2Vec` vector-sets are sorted to put the highest-frequency words 1st – no matter the order-of-appearance in the original data. That makes `restrict_vocab` more useful there, as often only results for the most-common words with the strongest vectors are most interesting.)

Comment: thanks a lot for the great answer. So what you propose is something like this? `model.docvecs.most_similar(model.docvecs['movie__fast_and_furious'], topn = 509)`. Please kindly correct me if I am wrong :)

Comment: Yes, then filter the results to include just tv-series.  For example, if `similars` holds the full results from your above statement, you could use a conditional list comprehension: `filtered_similars = [result for result in similars if result[0].startswith('tv_series')]`.